# Is there any npm library to push history in array?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I want to find the history of data change in Mongoose schema like when anybody updates or delete data, then I want to find the name of the user who deletes that field or if anybody updated that field then I want to find the last value and updated value and . then I want to push these in array named "history" in Mongoose schema.

Already used mongoose-diff-history, mongoose-history but these libraries create another collection.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Mongoose middleware](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html). It should not be that hard to utilize their hooks to write audit records to a collection of your choosing etc. You can hook into the model methods (`init`,  `save`, `remove` etc) and on their `pre` or `post` take actions. So before a record is deleted you can intercept that and write an audit etc.